# Excel separate numbers and numbers mixed

Tags: excel

Please help, is that a way to use functions to do this ? not filtering ! thanks

Column A

1. 1234
2. 2344
3. 23ERT
4. 33445
5. 11ABC

Result:

Column B

1. 1234
2. 2344
3. 33445

Columns C

1. 23ERT
2. 11ABC

Comment: What did you try so far to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

In **B1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$999)/(ISNUMBER(A:A)), ROW(1:1))),"")
```

and copy downward.  In **C1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$999)/(NOT(ISNUMBER(A:A))), ROW(1:1))),"")
```

and copy downward:

[image]